# file_get_contents() Connection timed out problem

Tags: php

i use `file_get_contents()` to get dinamic data.
here is my script...

```
$str = file_get_contents("http://cba.am/");
some script here...
```

it works fine for a long time, but now it returns `Connection timed out`.

and what is strange, when i run the script from local server, it works fine.

could you tell me why, and what can i do, to solve this.
maybe i must set the higher timeout time in `php.ini`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Try to extend script execution time by putting below line on top of your script:</strike>

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 14000); // or whatever value of time
```

**Update:**

When I added `www` to url, it worked:

```
file_get_contents("http://www.cba.am/");
```

Comment: Ahmed you're true. Thanks much, but can you explain such behavior?

Comment: @Syom: I am not a server stuff expert but i suspect it has to do with server settings that site is running on.

Comment: This is because the server settings dont have an alias set. A lot of times there is a vhost setting in apache that accepts both versions of the url - the www and non www. That is why you only have access with www.cba.com.

Answer (score 3):

The timeout for file_get_contents can be controlled with the following setting:

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 60);
```

Answer (score 2):

Their server is simply not configured to respond without the www.
It only responds to requests for www.cba.am, thus the timeout.